# Nomenclature for linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I was studying Linear Transformation and this symbol ↾ appears in this context:

ST = S(T ↾ I(T))

ST is the composition of the linear transformations S and T

I (T) image of T

It also says after this expression that we are only considering the values of S for any y belonging to I(T)...

But can someone clarifies me what exactly that symbol means?

Thanks!

Comment: $ST$ is the composition of $S$ and $T$ reduced to $I(T)$ the subspace "image of $T$" ?

Comment: i edited is it clearer now?

Comment: I proposed an explanation : when you restrict a linear operator $X \to Y$ to a linear subspace $E \subset X$ it becomes a linear operator $E \to Y$.

Comment: Most likely the symbol is "$\mid$", and as noted it means "restricted to". Please try and use $\LaTeX$ to get the symbols right.